# How to get all images that belong to a specific album in Laravel with Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get all images that belong to a specific album in Laravel with Eloquent. These are my tables:

```
Table: albums
Rows: id, name, description, user_id

Table: album_images
Rows: id, file_name

Table: album_album_image
Rows: album_id, album_image_id
```

My Album model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Album extends Model
{
    public function albumImages(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\AlbumImage', 'album_album_image','album_id','album_image_id');
    }
}
```

My AlbumImage model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AlbumImage extends Model
{
    public function album(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Album', 'album_album_image','album_image_id','album_id');
    }
}
```

Function that sends the $images variable to my specificAlbum view:

```
public function specificAlbum($albumName){
        $images =
        return view ('specificAlbum', ['images' => $images]);
    }
```

Now I need to have the $images variable get all the images that are associated with album with album name $albumName. Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why do you need the `album_album_image` table ? You could  keep an `album_id` column in `album_images` table.

Comment: Hmmm now that you mention it, I do not really need a intermediate table...

Comment: An intermediate table would be useful if you want to save one image to many albums. Something to consider if you would like that feature in your app in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the images relationship in Album model

```
class Album extends Model
{
   public function images(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\AlbumImage', 'album_album_image','album_id','album_image_id');
  }
}
```

Then:

```
public function specificAlbum($albumName)
{
    $album = Album::with('images')->where('name', '=', $albumName)->firstOrFail();

    return view ('specificAlbum', ['images' => $album->images]);
}
```

Comment: if $images = Album::with('images')->whereName($albumName)->get(); can I loop through $images to display all images? I only get 1 result in $images and it's not an image.

Comment: In the second code example, the result will be an `Album` model. You can then fetch its images using `$album->images`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/album/{kategori}', 'App\Http\Controllers\EmployeeController@album')->name('album');

Controller

public function album($kategori){
   
        $defaultAlbumId = null;
        switch($kategori) {
            case 'sports':
                $defaultAlbumId = 1; 
                break;
            case 'aesthetic':
                $defaultAlbumId = 2; 
                break;
            case 'animasi':
                $defaultAlbumId = 3; 
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
            $albumImages = Employee::where('kategori', $kategori)->get();
            return view('album', compact('albumImages')); 
        
    }

View

Route::get('/album/{kategori}', 'App\Http\Controllers\EmployeeController@album')->name('album');

Controller

public function album($kategori){
   
        $defaultAlbumId = null;
        switch($kategori) {
            case 'sports':
                $defaultAlbumId = 1; 
                break;
            case 'aesthetic':
                $defaultAlbumId = 2; 
                break;
            case 'animasi':
                $defaultAlbumId = 3; 
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
            $albumImages = Employee::where('kategori', $kategori)->get();
            return view('album', compact('albumImages')); 
        
    }

View

<body class="dark">
    @include('navbar')
    <center><h1>Album</h1></center>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        @if($albumImages->isEmpty())
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p>Tidak ada gambar yang ditemukan.</p>
            </div>
        @else
            @foreach($albumImages as $image)
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
                        <img src="{{ asset('foto/' . $image->gambar) }}" class="img-fluid" alt="{{ $image->judul }}">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="card-text">{{ $image->judul }}</p>
                            <p class="card-text">{{ $image->deskripsi }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        @endif
    </div>
    </div>

</body>
```